# when do facebook.request 2nd times, return OAuthException error code 2500

Tags: android, facebook

I try to get the album list from my facebook account, but there are more than 25 albums in my account, facebook only return 25 album when in each query.

1. first time I query the album first 25 albums list by normal use

   ```
       facebook.request(me/albums);
   ```

   and it returns album list successfully.
2. I use following to query next 25 albums, it will return Error code 2500

   ```
   facebook.request(me/albums?after=.......);
   ```

getting respose is

```
response = {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

If I add the access token manually in my request strings, like this

```
    facebook.request(me/albums?after=.......&access_token=......);
```

It will return erro code 190

```
 response = {"error":{"message":"Malformed access token ...............?access_token=...............","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the it will get problems with Error code 2500 when using command facebook.request.

The same command is working fine when query in Graph API Explorer website, but won't work when code running.

So finally I changed my way to get my album list. using FQL Query, then this problem solved.